# Reducing an integer set in z3 over addition

Tags: z3, z3py

I'm experimenting with (and failing at) reducing sets in z3 over operations like addition.  The idea is eventually to prove stuff about arbitrary reductions over reasonably-sized fixed-sized sets.

The first of the two examples below seems like it should yield `unsat`, but it doesn't. The second does work, but I would prefer not to use it as it requires incrementally fiddling with the model.

```py
def test_reduce():
  LIM = 5
  VARS = 10
  poss = [Int('i%d'%x) for x in range(VARS)]
  i = Int('i')
  s = Solver()
  arr = Array('arr', IntSort(), BoolSort())
  s.add(arr == Lambda(i, And(i < LIM, i >= 0)))
  a = arr
  for x in range(len(poss)):
    s.add(Implies(a != EmptySet(IntSort()), arr[poss[x]]))
    a = SetDel(a, poss[x])
  def final_stmt(l):
    if len(l) == 0: return 0
    return If(Not(arr[l[0]]), 0, l[0] + (0 if len(l) == 1 else final_stmt(l[1:])))
  sm = final_stmt(poss)
  s.push()
  s.add(sm == 1)
  assert s.check() == unsat
```

Interestingly, the example below works much better, but I'm not sure why...

```py
def test_reduce_with_loop_model():
  s = Solver()
  i = Int('i')
  arr = Array('arr', IntSort(), BoolSort())
  LIM = 1000
  s.add(arr == Lambda(i, And(i < LIM, i >= 0)))
  sm = 0
  f = Int(str(uuid4()))
  while True:
    s.push()
    s.add(arr[f])
    chk = s.check()
    if chk == unsat:
      s.pop()
      break
    tmp = s.model()[f]
    sm = sm + tmp
    s.pop()
    s.add(f != tmp)
  s.push()
  s.add(sm == sum(range(LIM)))
  assert s.check() == sat
  s.pop()
  s.push()
  s.add(sm == 11)
  assert s.check() == unsat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your call to:

```
    f = Int(str(uuid4()))
```

Is *inside* the loop in the first case, and is *outside* the loop in the second case. So, the second case simply works on one variable, and thus converges quickly. While the first one keeps creating variables and creates a much harder problem for z3. It's not surprising at all that these two behave significantly differently, as they encode entirely different constraints.

As a general note, reducing an array of elements with an operation is just not going to be an easy problem for z3. First, you *have* to assume an upper bound on the elements. And if that's the case, then why bother with `Lambda` or `Array` at all? Simply create a *Python* list of that many variables, and ignore the array logic completely. That is:

```
elts = [Int("s%d"%i) for i in range(100)]
```

And then to access the elements of your 'array', simply use Python accessor notation `elts[12]`.

Note that this *only* works if all your accesses are with a constant integer; i.e., your index cannot be symbolic. But if you're looking for proving reduction properties, that should suffice; and would be much more efficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this makes a lot of sense! In my larger context, sets can have known or unknown length, so I will encode the known-length sets as normal python objects and only resort to this sort of strategy for unknown lengths.